# Fortran: Array of arbitrary dimension?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, fortran

If I want to create an allocatable multidimensional array, I can say:

```
program test
    real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: x
    integer :: i,j

    allocate(x(5, 5))

    do i = 1,size(x,1)
        do j = 1,size(x,2)
            x(i,j) = i*j
        end do
    end do

    write(*,*) x

end program test
```

However, what if I don't know how many dimension `x` will be. Is there a way to accommodate that?

Comment: I wonder if you can use `RESHAPE()` to flatten, assign values, and then give it the original shape again.

Comment: What will govern the number of ranks?  And how will you use the array?

Comment: @francescalus, I will set the rank using a `integer, parameter :: ND = ` a number between 1 and 3. The use is a scalar field (voltage) which I want to solve Poisson's equation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation) using the finite difference method. So if I knew the rank (the number of dimensions) I could just say for example if `ND = 2`, `V(2:size(V,1)-1, 2:size(V,2)-1) = V(2:size(V,1), 2:size(V,2)-1) + V(1:size(V,1)-1, 2:size(V,2)-1) + V(2:size(V,1)-1, 2:size(V,2)) + V(2:size(V,1), 1:size(V,2)-1)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fortran: set array's rank at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500920/fortran-set-arrays-rank-at-runtime)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newer compilers allow the use of assumed-rank objects for interoperability.
I think that is what you are looking for. But this is for call to functions or subroutines. The function or subroutine declares the dummy argument as assumed-rank and the actual rank is passed with the actual argument at runtime.

Example from IBM website:

```
REAL :: a0
REAL :: a1(10)
REAL :: a2(10, 20)
REAL, POINTER :: a3(:,:,:)

CALL sub1(a0)
CALL sub1(a1)
CALL sub1(a2)
CALL sub1(a3)

CONTAINS
    SUBROUTINE sub1(a)
        REAL :: a(..)
        PRINT *, RANK(a)
    END

END
```

follow [this](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH4D_15.1.0/com.ibm.xlf151.aix.doc/language_ref/assumedrankobject.html) or [that](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH4D_15.1.0/com.ibm.xlf151.aix.doc/language_ref/assumedrankobj.html?lang=en) for more details

Comment: Note that assumed-rank is part of TS 29113:2012 and included in the  Fortran2015 draft.  Recent versions of gfortran and ifort should also support this but support is probably relatively recent e.g. in the last 3 years at most.

Comment: I tried with both ifort 14 and 15. Both of them spit out `error #5082: Syntax error, found '.' when expecting one of: <IDENTIFIER>
                REAL :: a(..)
---------------------------^
test.f90(8): error #6634: The shape matching rules of actual arguments and dummy arguments have been violated.   [A1]
        CALL sub1(a1)
------------------^`

Comment: @user1543042 It looks like ifort 16 is required for assumed rank support.

Comment: @user1543042, you do not have the latest compiler to use the feature. Either you re-think your design or you upgrade your compiler. It is important to answer for yourself the comment of francescalus: "What will govern the number of ranks? And how will you use the array?"

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're trying to carry out stencil computations across an array of rank-1, -2 or -3 -- this isn't quite the same as needing arrays of arbitrary rank.  And assumed-rank arrays are really only applicable when passing an array argument to a routine, there's no mechanism even in the forthcoming standard for declaring an array to have a rank determined at run-time.

If you're impatient to get on with your code and your compiler doesn't yet implement TS 29113:2012 perhaps the following approach will appeal to you.

```
   real, dimension(:,:,:), allocatable :: voltage_field

   if (nd == 1) allocate(voltage_field(nx,1,1))
   if (nd == 2) allocate(voltage_field(nx,ny,1))       
   if (nd == 3) allocate(voltage_field(nx,ny,nz))
```

Your current approach faces the problem of not knowing, in advance of knowing the number of dimensions in the field, how many nearest-neighbours to consider in the stencil, so you might find yourself writing 3 versions of each stencil update.  If you simply abuse a rank-3 array of size `nx*1*1` to represent a 1D problem (*mutatis mutandis* a 2D problem) you always have 3 sets of nearest-neighbours in each stencil calculation.  It's just that in the flattened dimensions the nearest neighbour is, well, either a ghost cell containing a boundary value, or the cell itself if your space wraps round.

Writing your code to work always in 3 dimensions but to make no assumptions about the extent of at least two of them will, I think, be easier than writing rank-sensitive code.  But I haven't given the matter a lot of thought and I haven't really thought too much about its impact on your f-d scheme.